# Align text to this slider image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align text to different images for a presentation as a slider, the problem is that it depends on the number of items and that i use translated text (english/spanish) and i need to work on both no matter how long the text is (usually no more than 25 characters). it's "working" for two and three items but i need it to be more dynamically as the text can vary and this is just a test.

The images are quite large so i ajusted it to 800px to fit perfect on my template dont know if i should change the images or tried to fit the text content or both.

[image]

This is what i have so far, i tried dividing the entire row size to each column inside on % and px
for example if there's 2 items each col width should be set to 50% but is not working so i tried different values (in this case two-items 42%) but is not align yet.

```css
  .slider-image {
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
}

.slider-text {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.two-items .col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /*max-width: 347px;*/
  width: 42%;
}

.three-items .col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /*max-width: 260px;*/
  width: 31%;
}

.four-items .col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* max-width: 207px; */
  width: 24%;
}

.five-items .col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /*max-width: 166px;*/
  width: 19%;
}

.header-item {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10.6pt;
  color: #b5d8e4;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.active {
  color: black !important;
```

```html
<div class="container slide-height">
  <div class="row slider-text two-items ">
    <div class="col header-item active"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span></div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img class="slider-image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/4yDwGBHZ/indicador-2-1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="row slider-text three-items ">
    <div class="col header-item active"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span></div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item">Prueba Costs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img class="slider-image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/MZg8XwyZ/indicador-3-1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="row slider-text four-items ">
    <div class="col header-item active"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span></div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item">Prueba Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item">Prueba Costs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img class="slider-image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/5NvWCr3B/indicador-cuatro-1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="row slider-text five-items ">
    <div class="col header-item active"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span></div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
    <div class="col header-item"><span class="fst-italic">Prueba</span> Costs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img class="slider-image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QNF3XCKn/indicador-5-1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using flex (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex), and since your slider images don't correspond to 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 you will have pain to align text.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not responsive at the moment.
Since you use a responsive structure with `.container`, your images should be `100%` filling the width of the `.col`.

```
.slider-image {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%; /*800px*/
}
```

Then for your 3th and 4th row personally I would adjust the images to be more aligned. As of now they start rather aligned to the edge instead of centered. That's for the easy approach...

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/pkgcbe3v/)**

---

If you can break the images down, perhaps make an svg (or CSS shape) out of it, you can keep it all contained to a single class with different variants.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/rka1cz2e/)**

For the shapes I've introduced a new `div.shape` inside your `.header-item`. This will hold the bullet shape on the pseudo `:before` and the diamond on `:after`. To solve the border(s) we can use the `.header-item` itself.

```
/* border shapes */
.header-item:before,
.header-item:after {
    bottom: 60px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* vertical border */
.header-item:before {
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #b5d8e4;
    left: calc(50% - 0.5px);
}

/* horizontal border */
.header-item:after {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #b5d8e4;
    left: 0;
}

/* bullet & diamond */
.shape:before,
.shape:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #b5d8e4;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

/* bullet */
.shape:before {
    top: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;  
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

/* diamond */
.shape:after {
    top: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;  
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* states */
.active .shape:before,
.active .shape:after {
    background-color: #b5d8e4;
}
```